# Tensorflow: slicing PartitionedVariable

Tags: tensorflow

I have created a TensorFlow `PartitionedVariable` object. Unfortunately I need to slice it at some other point of my program (not according to how the variable is partitioned). Unfortunately when I try the obvious (`X[count:]`), I get the error `TypeError: PartitionedVariable object has no attribute getitem`. Is it a bug, or is there any workaround of how to slice `PartitionedVariable`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to use `tf.slice()`.

```
tf.slice(X, [count], [-1])
```

in your case.